# Grouping months by quarter over multiple years depending on a dynamic start month

Tags: mysql

Using **MySQL** and **PHP** I am building a **JSON** array to populate a data table.

For the purposed of my question suppose the data table has the following columns:

```
Year: 2010,2011,2012,2013...<br/>
Month: 1,2,3,4,5...<br/>
Value: 100, 150, 200 etc...<br/>
```

The table structure cannot be altered and my solution needs come into the MySQL query

The data can be viewed either monthly, quarterly or yearly. Monthly and yearly is achieved easily through grouping by year and month.

Quarterly data can be grouped by calendar quarter (Jan-Mar, Apr-Jun, Jul-Sep, Oct-Dec) by this group statement:

```
GROUP BY year, round((month/3)+0.3,0)
```

So where Jan, Feb and March might all have 100 for their value the summed result is 300, same for other months.

Now my problem comes when I want to group values by a financial quarter, for example a quarter that starts in Feb, or any other quarters.

I have a statement that works for the quarter grouping using two variables that can be accessed via the SQL query, start_year (i.e. 2014) and start_month (i.e. 2)

```
GROUP BY year, (((round(((((month-(start_month-1))+((year-start_year)*12))-((year-start_year)*12))/3)+0.33,0)/4)+4)-floor(((round(((((month-(start_month, '%m')-1))+((year-start_year)*12))-((year-start_year*12))/3)+0.33,0)/4)+4)))*12
```

which basically will assign a 0,3,6,9 value to each calendar month for the purposes of grouping.

In the financial year starting February this works fine for quarters 1-3, however breaks for the final quarter as it includes Nov and Dec 2014 data and Jan from 2015.

As a result I get 5 rows of data instead of 4.

This is because of the preceding GROUP by year clause, an important addition as we might want to generate a table that views sequential quarters for multiple years.

So what I am looking for is a way of grouping the years together by offsetting the start month.

So when the year starts in Jan it will group Jan-Dec but if we change that to starting Feb it will group Feb-Jan.

Any ideas, suggestions most welcome!

Regards,
Carl

Comment: You know there's a quarter function, right?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem just now (a Moodle report aggregating assignment scores by year and quarter) with something like this:

```
select year(from_unixtime(s.timemarked)) as year, quarter(from_unixtime(s.timemarked)) % 4 + 1 as quarter, count(distinct data1) as "tickets graded" from mdlassignment_submissions s where grade >= 0 group by year, quarter order by year, quarter;
```

The relevant part for what you're doing is `quarter(from_unixtime(s.timemarked)) % 4 + 1 as quarter`

As another commenter pointed out, MySQL has a `quarter()` function, but it doesn't do financial quarters. However, since (as I understand it, at least, based on consulting the relevant wikipedia page) financial quarters are just offset by 1, the `% 4 + 1` at the end should convert it.